# How to automate clicking a link inside a WebView

Tags: android, webview

Ok, guys. I know it sounds weird but what I want to achieve is when i run the app. The webview first load the link and after I enter all the details, it must automatically click a button inside the webview. Is there any possible way to do this?? I have tried with loading different links in order to open the new window.

for example,

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ourBrow = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvBrowser);
    // cancel the web intent that default in android setting
    ourBrow.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    url = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSC);

    // webView settings
    ourBrow.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    ourBrow.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    ourBrow.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    Button SCode = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btSCode);
    loadUrl("http://www.google.com.au");
```

this part works well, but what I want is when the length inside the search bar is equal to 4, the "search" button will automatically press

thanks so much for the help!!!

Comment: where is the search bar in the program?

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps do this by executing some awkward javascript in the webview.

To just issue the click you could probably do something like

```
ourBrow.loadUrl("javascript:getElementById('button_id').click()");
```

Since you need to wait for the search bar to have a lenght of 4 you will probably want to register a listener on the field in javascript and issue the click there. I can't tell you the best way to do this, but you will probably need to set an eventlistener for 'change' or set onKeyUp or something similar and see if the field is of length >= 4 then issue the click. You could nest all of this in the javascript row.

Set it after the page has loaded, that is. Set a [WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) on the webview and load the javascript in the `onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)` callback or something similar.

Comment: hi, Sebastian Olsson, thanks so much for your help, can you show me more detail about this code "ourBrow.loadUrl("javascript:getElementById('button_id').click()") "